# Sidebar scrolling issue

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, sidebar

My problem is that I want to fix sidebar on my website somehow it is
changing its position with scroll https://helloacademy.co/course/the-complete-digital-marketing-course/ I wants it fixed on the top

initially, I fix it with this CSS. but is there any better solution?

```
.course_header5_sideblock {
    transform: translateY(0px)!important;
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the solution you're using? It looks like a `scroll` listener is attached to the `window` and has something to do with the event that changes that element's `translateY` value (if you remove the CSS rule you showed above, and issue `$(window).off('scroll')` in the console, it seems to keep its place appropriately), but if your solution works, is there a need to find another way?

Comment: If you search for `t(".course_h` in the included JS file `wplms.min.js` you can see the listener that's affecting this. You may want to "pretty print" the JS, though, it's a little tough to decipher minified.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript code that's affecting the sidebar is in `wplms.min.js` like mark.hch commented.

Your CSS solution is probably the easiest way to implement a solution, and unless you have an issue using `!important` it seems to be fine.

That said, if you want to edit the JS file directly and remove this functionality, you'll want to remove this code snippet:

```
    var e = function() {
        t(".course_header5_sideblock").each(function() {
            if (Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0) > 992) {
                var e = t(this).parent().width(),
                    n = (t(".pusher > .fix").height(), t("#content").offset().top + t("#content").height() - t(this).height());
                t(this).css("width", e + "px");
                var i = t(this);
                t(window).scroll(function(e) {
                    var o = t(this).scrollTop();
                    o < n && i.css("transform", "translateY(" + o + "px)")
                })
            } else t(this).css("width", "")
        })
    };
```

When pretty printed, this snippet is on lines 5267-5280.

**Note,** when/if you update the WPLMS plugin, this edit will be overwritten, so CSS is probably the best solution.